# Objects keep losing their more specific type?

Tags: javascript, casting

I've been struggling with the loosely-typed nature of JavaScript lately. I've been writing a program that makes API calls to fetch data, and stores the resulting data in a custom class. One of the values of the custom class is a date, which is supposed to be of the `Date` type. Before creating the object, I always convert the date value to a proper `Date` object before passing it into the constructor.

For reference, this is what the class looks like:

```
class Item {
    constructor(title, date) {
      this.title = title;
      this.date = date;
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the date value and compare it to another date value later on, it seems to have reverted to a normal object type, as the console claims `item.date.compare` isn't a function. Logging has indicated the type of the object is a generic object, but that it's an instance of `Date`. But I haven't been able to figure out how to treat it as specifically a `Date` object.

As of now I've tried casting, which hasn't worked. Namely, I've tried doing `item.date as Date` as well as `Object.create(Date, item.date)`. Neither has worked so far. What am I missing?

Comment: Without seeing the code involved in handling the values, it's hard to say.

Comment: You need to show us a minimal working version of your code. Also, you are making an "instance" of `Item`, right?

Comment: Something is changing the variable, it's that simple.  Any time you use the variable, make sure you console.log the value and type of it.  Also, what they said - more code, or we can't help other than vague suggestions.

Comment: Be careful of global scope.  If you're declaring the variable inside a function with `var`, it's scoped to that function.  If you didn't use `var` it's a global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are instantiating your class properly and passing the correct data, you'll have a date.

The reason you are getting your error is simple, The **[JavaScript `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** type doesn't have a `compare` method.

See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)** for how to compare dates.

```js
class Item {
    constructor(title, date) {
      this.title = title;
      this.date = date;
    }
}

var myItem = new Item("test instance", new Date());

console.log(myItem.date.constructor, myItem.date);
```